Understanding a question in multivariable calculus

Define $f$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ by  \begin{equation}
    f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2 \end{equation}
Let $S$ be the set of all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ at which $f(x,y)=0$.
Find those points of $S$ that have no neighbourhoods in which the
equation can be solved for $y$ in terms of $x$ (or vice-versa).

What does this question mean, and how can I solve $2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2=0$?
Thanks

The question is asking about where you can solve the equation $f(x,y)=0$ locally by some function $y$ so that $f(x,y(x))=0$ (or similarly for the other variable). This does not necessarily mean you have to solve the equation (and it doesn't really look like an equation you can just solve like that). Have a look at the statement of the implicit function theorem

How do you find the function $y$ ?

It's not always that you can, and for this problem you don't have to. Again, look at the statement of the implicit function theorem

The function $y=y(x)$ in the above comment(s) is an "implicit function", we do not have a formula for it, just a theoretical statement that there is one such function (with given smoothness properties) locally, i.e. in some suitable neighborhood of a point of $S$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem This is the reason for the name of the theorem. (Sometimes "we can solve", but the chosen/resulted function is not differentiable at that point.)

@dan_fulea so without the implicit function, how can I find those points?

A plot may help. We apply the implicit function theorem, and know that "a lot of points"  $(x_0,y_0)\in S$ have locally an explicit solution $y=y(x)$ so that $f(x,y(x))=0$ for all $x$ "around" the fixed $x_0$, respectively an explicit solution $x=x(y)$ so that $f(x(y), y)=0$ for all $y$ near the fixed $y_0$. Then we look closer with the methods of algebra at the remained points. To have a first impression, what happens in the cases of the equations $x^3=y^5$, $x^3=y^2$, $x^3=y^4$ in each case near the "critical" point $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$?

@dan_fulea In those cases you obtain a valid equality. I have found the maximum and minimum of the function at hand, these are respectively at (0,1) and (-1,0). Can I do the same you have done on those points?

In the above cases we have different situations, the point of interest for me, just to have toy examples for the present question, was the point $(0,0)$. For $x^3=y^5$ we have solutions of the shape $x=y^{5/3}$, respectively $y=x^{3/5}$ (with different smoothness properties). But for $x^3=y^2$ there is no solution for $x<0$. So locally near $x_0=0$ we have no solution. (We have one only on right neighborhoods.) Now for the given $f$, i took a closer look, the equation factorizes i think as:$$0=(2 , x^{2} - 2 , x y + 2 , y^{2} - 3 , x + 3 , y);(x + y)\ .$$And that $x+y$ helps us...

@dan_fulea absolutely. $x,y=(-1,1)$ or (1,-1)! Thanks for this.

By the inverse function theorem, for any point $(x,y)$ such that
$$
\partial_y f(x,y)=6y(y+1) \ne 0
$$
The function can be expressed as
$$
f(x,y)=f(x,g(x))
$$
for some continuously differentiable function.
for the same theorem, if
$$
6x(x-1) \ne 0
$$
then, locally
$$
f(x,y)=f(h(y),y)
$$
The only points in which both the derivative are $0$ are
$$
(0,0), (0,-1), (1,0), (1,-1)
$$
for these points there is no implicit function
